# Чтение чисел из файла

Tags: потоки-данных, java

Всем привет.
Такая задача: нужно считать с файла числа, сделать с ними определенные манипуляции, затем вывести на консоль. Какие классы лучше использовать для ввода/вывода?

Comment: В каком формате числа? Приведите пример нескольких строк файла.

Comment: 6 44 55 103 1664

или

каждое в новой строке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала нужно создать объект файла.

```
File f = new File("/path/to/file");
```

Потом идём по пути наименьшего сопротивления, поэтому используем befferedReader

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
}
```